# IO Error when reading disc

Tags: io, disc

I get this error when i tried to read the DVD DL i burnt

```
The request could not be performed because of an i/o error
```

Usually i get crc errors but not this time. Whats wrong and how do i fix it? what is strange was when nero with verifying the contents it locked to at XY%. I was able to abort, it didnt freeze. But i found this strange as well.

Comment: What kind of a DVD writer you are using? Is it old? Is it in a laptop? If in laptop - were you burning while plugged in a wall or on batteries? If it is one of the above (or all together :] ) then I'd advise to try burning again on some other drive. If your DVD got screwed up, then there isn't much to do with it besides throwing out or giving to kids to play with :]

Comment: try with another DVD of any make other the one you tried to burn.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten this problem a few times, there has been multiple causes. First, I'd check that the DVD isn't the problem by testing it on another computer or burning another copy. Make sure you burn at a slow speed (even 4x to be sure) and let it verify again. If all goes well and you still get problems, it's probably the drive. Check the connectors before tossing it though.

Comment: throwing a reboot into that mix of suggestions might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been burning data through Nero and got an error (or stuck) on the 'verify data' stage, then most probably your DVD will not be usable. Try burning again, on another DVD (or with another drive, preferably).

If you really need to get that data off it, then you may try using one of the CD/DVD data recovery tools. Like [IsoBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/isobuster.php), for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you burned a coaster (or have a hardware failure, but much less likely). No way to fix it other than trying to read it in a different drive that may have better error correction, or burning it again.

Answer (score -3):

Step 1

Shut down the computer and restart it. If you see an I/O error only once, restarting the machine may fix it without further action. Sometimes, the Windows SWAP file, or temporary cache file, may become corrupted by spyware or poorly written software that writes too much data or reduces the size of the SWAP file temporarily. If this occurs, Windows may report an I/O error stating it cannot read or write data to the "C:" drive. Restarting the computer flushes the temporary cache files and fixes the problem. However, you should run your anti-malware or antivirus software after restarting the computer to avoid software related I/O errors in the future.
Step 2

Update the device driver for the drive or storage device if restarting the computer does not fix the I/O errors. Open a Web browser and visit the support website of the manufacturer of the drive or storage device. Download the latest Windows driver for the device and save it to your computer. Open Windows Explorer, double-click the download file and then follow the prompts to install the updated driver on your computer. Restart the computer after updating the device driver and then use the machine normally to see if it corrected the I/O error problems.
Step 3

Run the Windows Chkdsk tool to see if the drive or storage device has bad sectors or media causing the I/O errors. To run Chkdsk, click the Start button, then type "Chkdsk /R Z:" where "Z:" is the drive letter of the drive or storage device causing the I/O errors. Press the "Enter" key to run the utility in a new Command Prompt window. Windows prompts you to run the utility when you restart the computer because it cannot gain exclusive access the drive or device. When prompted press "Y" to restart the computer. Windows shuts down the computer and restarts it. After the computer restarts, the Chkdsk command line utility launches automatically and scans the disk for errors. If the utility finds bad sectors or other problems with the drive, it attempts to repair them automatically. After the Chkdsk utility finishes scanning and repairing the drive, the computer restarts and boots into Windows.
Step 4

Check the cable connection for the drive or storage device. If the device is an external hard drive or optical drive, disconnect and reconnect its USB data cable and see if that corrects the I/O problems. If the device is an internal drive, shut down the computer and disconnect all external cables, and then use the Phillips screwdriver to remove the side panel or access cover. Check the cable connections for all of the drives in the computer and ensure they are tight and secure. Check the connections on the rear of the drives, as well as on the motherboard. When checking the cable connections, check the power cable connections from the power supply as well.

Comment: copy pasted from http://techchannel.radioshack.com/fix-o-device-error-1693.html I think

Comment: Plus it's not going to solve his problem